# How can i bind a Database field value to a hidden field inside a gridview

Tags: asp.net, mysql, gridview, hiddenfield

I use the following to bind a field from  the table to a hidden field inside a gridview but i am getting the error as System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'AccountType'.

This is how I assigned

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAccntType" runat="Server" Value='<%#Eval("AccountType") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Is it correct or do I have to make any corrections?

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspGetEmployeeBankDate`(_EmpID INT(11),
 _BankTypeID varchar(10),_AccountType varchar(10))
BEGIN
select EmpID,BankTypeID,DATE_FORMAT(StartDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
as StartDate,DATE_FORMAT(EndDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as EndDate 
from tblemployeebankdata where EmpID=_EmpID and BankTypeID=_BankTypeID 
 and AccountType=_AccountType;

END
```

Sample code

```
       if (mlocal_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow drRow in mlocal_ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (drRow["BankTypeID"].ToString() == "DbalC")
                {
                    pnlGrid.Visible = false;
                    grdBank.Visible = true;
                    //grdData.Visible = false;

                    strEmpID = HiddenField1.Value;
                    string AccntType = drRow["AccountType"].ToString();
                    string strBankTypeID = drRow["BankTypeID"].ToString();
                    string mlocal_strStoredProcName = StoredProcNames.tblEmployeeBankdetails_uspEmployeeBankdetailsDate;
                    mlocal_ds = new DataSet();
                    oEmployee.SelectId(out mlocal_ds, mlocal_strStoredProcName, strEmpID, strBankTypeID,AccntType); // here the stored procedure is executed
                    grdBank.DataSource = mlocal_ds;
                    grdBank.DataBind();
                    pnlChckAcc.Visible = false;
                    pnlPrimary.Visible = false;
                    pnlSecond.Visible = false;
                    pnlSecondary.Visible = false;
                    pnlFirst.Visible = false;
                    pnlEditInfo.Visible = false;
                    break;
                }
```

My grid view

```
     <asp:GridView ID="grdBank" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
            CssClass="grid" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="349px" Visible="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtnBank" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdbtnBank_CheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>                        
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAccntType" runat="Server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccountType") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpID" HeaderText="EmpID">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="intitalitefname" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BankTypeID" HeaderText="BankTypeID">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="intitalitefname" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="intitalitefname" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="End Date">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="intitalitefname" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                nodata to display
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I used to try to do things like this with the gridview but decided it was faster and more practical to dynamically build my own table with a stringbuilder and linq to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Muhammed Akhtar said your original datasource doesn't include the AccountType field so you can't bind this to anything

You need to change your Stored Procedure to:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspGetEmployeeBankDate`(_EmpID INT(11),

_BankTypeID varchar(10),_AccountType varchar(10))
BEGIN
select AccountType, EmpID,BankTypeID,DATE_FORMAT(StartDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
as StartDate,DATE_FORMAT(EndDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as EndDate 
from tblemployeebankdata where EmpID=_EmpID and BankTypeID=_BankTypeID 
 and AccountType=_AccountType;

END
```

The I've modified is right at the beginning of your "select" which now includes the AccountType field.  If you don't include this field in your original select it's not going to be included in the datasource you get back which in turn means you can't bind it

Hope that helps

Dave

Comment: Thanks Dave a minor mistake i made

Answer (score 0):

you should use the notation: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccountType") %>

Comment: My field in table is a primary key will this make an issue

Comment: what object are you binding to your GridView? a DataTable?

Comment: I am binding using Datasource

Comment: yes but what? tell us the table structure and show us how you load the data and how you bind it to the GridView

Comment: One question as i have taken the account type as hidden field is it necessary to pass that while binding the gridivew